Moving a project from one folder to a subfolder
I've built a react app in VsCode and after a while wanted to put it in a subfolder of the folder it's currently in, but after I've put it inside the subfolder everytime I've tried to run it I get an error 'Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory', how can I fix it?

Check that all configurations point correctly to the new paths.
Check these:

Make sure that the package.json file is present in the new subdirectory;
Install the dependencies again: npm install;
Check for configuration files that refer to specific paths .env, webpack.config.js, tsconfig.json and make sure the paths are updated according to the new folder structure;
Ensure that the execution scripts in the package.json file do not contain absolute or relative paths that still point to the old folder;
If you still experience problems, it may be useful to clear the npm cache: npm cache clean --force.

